# Angular tabs re-ordering themselves onClick on newest version of Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

[image: tab-behavior]In my AngularJS app, I'm using a custom tabs directive to create several clickable tabs. On the newest version of chrome (77.0.3865.90), clicking on of these tabs causes the clicked tab to unexpectedly re-order itself. (The tab, which was on the right before, slides all the way to the left). In addition, some tabs are being covered by other tabs.

Does anyone know if this is due to a regression in the newest version of chrome? I don't see this behavior in Firefox or Edge.

Comment: Are you talking about browser tabs?

Comment: No I'm not talking about the chrome browser tabs. I'm referring to a custom angular directive made to look like tabs, each of which are clickable and display similar content. Similar to a bootstrap accordion: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Do you have a demo of the issue? If you wrote the code yourself all I can say is that you probably wrote it to behave that way. If your tabs are objects stored in an array then I doubt any update to Chrome would have an influence on the sorting of that array.

Comment: I recorded a small demo of the issue using Quicktime but I'm not sure how to upload a .mov file to this question. I've pasted a screenshot where you can kind of see one tab overlaying another tab. I didn't write the code myself but will inspect it more closely.

Comment: Use the Developer Console to inspect the element and use the computed style tab to determine the CSS causing the issue. Also check the Developer Console for messages. Newer versions of Chrome will reject style sheets when strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue in my app. I'm assuming a chrome update fixed this issue.